# Asyncpg: UPDATE with UNNEST much slower than using FROM VALUES

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, asyncpg

I have the following table:

```
create table foo (id serial primary key, ts date, value int);
```

Populated with 10k records already. Now I'm trying to find a way to efficiently update multiple rows in one go, so I wrote this code to compare two approaches (references: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246753/updating-multiple-values-at-a-time) for the first method, [here](https://www.atdatabases.org/blog/2022/01/21/optimizing-postgres-using-unnest) for the second):

```
import asyncpg
import asyncio
import time

async def main():
    c = await asyncpg.connect(user='foo', password='bar', database='foodb', host='192.168.100.1')

    # prepare data
    arr = []
    arr2 = [[], []]
    for i in range(10001):
        row = (i+1, i)
        arr.append(row)
        arr2[0].append(row[0])
        arr2[1].append(row[1])


    # using FROM VALUES
    values = ",".join([ f"{i}" for i in arr ])
    q = f"UPDATE foo SET value = v.value FROM(VALUES {values}) AS v(id, value) WHERE v.id = foo.id;"
    start_time = time.time()
    await c.execute(q)
    print(f"from values: {time.time() - start_time}")

    # using UNNEST
    q = "UPDATE foo SET value = v.value FROM ( SELECT * FROM UNNEST($1::int[], $2::int[])) AS v(id, value) WHERE foo.id = v.id;"
    start_time = time.time()
    await c.execute(q, *arr2)
    print(f"unnest: {time.time() - start_time}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The first method is consistently *much* faster than the second.
The thing I don't like about the first method is that (as far as I can tell - corrections welcome) it cannot be used with `$x` placeholders for the `VALUES` part, so one is forced to manually build the string (which is also unsafe from an SQL injection point of view I believe).

So my questions:

- can `VALUES` be built dynamically and used with placeholders?
- is `UNNEST` really slower or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, getting similar times for each.   For example, 0.048 for the first and 0.052 for the second.  What version of the software (both PostgreSQL and python and modules) are you using?

Comment: This is postgres 14.2, python 3.9.2, asyncpg 0.27.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this in v14, but only when JIT is enabled, and only on an older compilation.  I assume that is because newer compilations use a newer version of some llvm-dependent library (but both report the same version of llvm itself). The slow query is not the UNNEST query itself, but rather some introspection query which asyncpg uses, apparently to determine the types of the arguments to UNNEST. Whatever the change was, I don't know how to undo it for further testing.

Since I can't get the slowness to reproduce in new compilations, the fact that v15 is faster is ambiguous; either something was fixed in v15, or just because it was compiled more recently.

Since I think having jit be on by default was a mistake (by the PostgreSQL developers) in the first place, I would say you should just turn jit off and be done with it.

Comment: Indeed using `set jit=off;` in the connection just before running the updates lowers all times in general, and specifically brings the times for the two original methods much closer, to the point that `UNNEST` is now on par with the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't profile `UNNEST` performance, but as for your 1st question (regarding `$x` phaceolders) [`con.executemany`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.connection.Connection.executemany) is a proper choice for multiple updates:

```
q = "UPDATE foo SET value = $2 WHERE id = $1;"
await c.executemany(q, arr)
```

Comment: This is interesting, I was under the impression that `executemany` in asyncpg runs multiple statements instead of a single one? UPDATE: [here](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/346) they mention an improvement, but from what I understand it's still running multiple statements.

Comment: @persson, you asked about placeholders - it allows you that. And it's  an atomic operation, which means that either all executions succeed, or none at all.

Comment: I asked about placeholders when using `VALUES FROM`, but thanks anyway, I'll check `executemany` out.

Comment: Profiling `executemany` seems to perform better than `UNNEST`, but still slower than the `UPDATE FROM VALUES` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you are unable to bind arrays, my work around is to dynamically build the bind tokens, not the whole substitution...

A rough and ready example being...

```
arr = []
for i in range(10001):
  arr.append(i+1)
  arr.append(i)

tokens = ",".join([ "(?,?)" for i in range(10001) ]
q = f"UPDATE foo SET value = v.value FROM(VALUES {tokens}) AS v(id, value) WHERE v.id = foo.id;"

await c.execute(q, *arr)
```

Comment: Ok since asyncpg uses numbered placeholders, the code should be more something like ```tokens = ",".join([ f"(${i+1}::int,${i+2}::int)" for i in range(0, 20002, 2) ])``` but the idea is clear. Trying this, seems to be better than the other methods but still slightly slower than the first one (possibly due to the overhead of having 20k placeholders...)

Comment: @persson Is the type cast `::int` strictly necessary? You don't have it in your first example (I haven't played with pg in quite a while, and then it was with PSYCOpg2)

Comment: Apparently it is, otherwise you get an error: ```asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedFunctionError: operator does not exist: text = integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.```. [This](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/975) seems to provide some background.